# Adding results from array together to get totals

Tags: jquery, ajax

Afternoon,
I have an array retreived via an AJAX call. It brings back the following results, sometimes with multiple items

```
 itemQty: 1
 productBrand: "Brand"
 productPrice: "6.25"
 productShipping: "0.35"
 productSku: "sku"
 productTitle: "ProdTitle"
 OrderId: 123
```

Below is my jQuery code to sort and add the items together to make the sub total, shipping, then grand total.

```
 var ordRes = result;

 var subTotal = (ordRes.productPrice * parseInt(ordRes.itemQty)).toFixed(2);
 var orderTotal = (parseFloat(ordRes.productShipping) + parseFloat(subTotal)).toFixed(2);

 $('#ordSubTotal').text("£" + subTotal);
 $('#ordShipping').text("£" + ordRes.productShipping);
 $('#ordTotal').text("£" + orderTotal);
```

however when i bring back multiple items i am unable to add them together in subTotal, and orderTotal. can someone please shed some light on this for me?

*** Returned JSON ***

```
 {
"d": [
    {
        "__type": "ABO.GetOrdersDetails",
        "tweOrderId": 123,
        "productSku": "sku",
        "productTitle": "ProdTitle",
        "productBrand": "Brand",
        "itemQty": 1,
        "productPrice": "6.25",
        "productShipping": "0.35"
    },
    {
        "__type": "ABO.GetOrdersDetails",
        "tweOrderId": 123,
        "productSku": "sku",
        "productTitle": "ProdTitle",
        "productBrand": "Brand",
        "itemQty": 2,
        "productPrice": "82.58",
        "productShipping": "4.60"
    }
 ]
 }
```

Comment: what seems to beh the problem?

Comment: can you show the JSON that gets returned from your service call?

Comment: How have you tried going about adding the prices for multiple products?

Comment: I have just come to test when multiple products are ordered, It works fine if there is just one. 

It is not added all the totals from the array back, the JSON contains the above basically. I have checked the JSON, which is valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (result.constructor != Array) {
    result = [result];
}

var subTotal = 0, orderTotal = 0;
for (var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var tmp = parseFloat(result[i].productPrice) * result[i].itemQty;
    orderTotal += (parseFloat(result[i].productShipping) + tmp);
    subTotal += tmp;
}

$('#ordSubTotal').text("£" + subTotal.toFixed(2));
$('#ordTotal').text("£" + orderTotal.toFixed(2));
```

Maybe it helps for you.

Comment: I am getting expected ";" in the += bits

Comment: how can i get the shipping price back too please?

Comment: How it calculates? The sum of all or average?